# HyperThyroidism

Tags: dermatology, hyperthyroid

I am 46 years old, female. My TSH levels are **8.10**. Due to this, my skin is becoming **wrinkled around the neck** and I look older than my age. I also have **excessive hairfall** and **reduced vision** due to this. I have already consulted a dermatologist to reduce wrinkles. Besides that , any of your advices are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is more of a question and answer site, not really a discussion type site. I would advise you to keep doing what your dermatologist recommends, and see if he/she has any other recommendations for treatment supplementation.

Answer (score 0):

If your TSH levels are too high, you have **hypo**thyroidism.
Beneath hairloss other symptoms are listlesness, dry skin, feeling cold or  gaining weight easily.
The TSH should be between 0.4 and 4 ([1](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/2074091-overview)).
The best would be to visit an internist/endocrinologist and start a L-thyroxine substitution. 
If the wrinkles are because of the hypothyroidism, the substitution should solve the problem.

*Why is a high TSH a marker of a Hypothyreosis?*

Click [here](http://www.endocrinesurgeon.co.uk/images/stories/content/hormonal-control-of-thyroid.jpg) for an image of the thyroid hormone controll loop.

The hypothalamus constantly screens the bloodlevels of thyroid hormones. If they are too low, it releases TRH (thyreotropin releasing hormone). TRH stimulates the pituary gland to produce TSH (Thyrotropin or thyroidea stimulating hormone). An increase in TRH leads to an increase of TSH. TSH than stimulates the thyroid gland to produce T4 which finally becomes T3, the active thyroid hormone, in the tissue (the most conversion from T4 to T3 happens in the brain).

If there is a lack of thyroid hormone, the hypothalmus senses it and through increased TRH more TSH ist produced. However if the thyroid gland is insufficient and can't respond to elevated TSH levels with producing T4 there is no negative feedback, thus leading to a further increase of TSH levels. That's why high TSH levels indicate **hypo**thyroidism. TSH under 0.4 is therefore an indicator for **hyper**thyroidism.

Hypothyroidism is usually harmless and is treated with L-Thyroxine (artificial T4) substitution.

Comment: L-Thyroxine isn't artificial T3, it is artifical T4. Artifical T3 is liothyronine, which is needed in a (possibly small) subgroup of hypothyroid patients. Although they usually mark hypothyroidism, elevated TSH concentrations may in very rare cases accompany hyperthyroidism (i.e. secondary hyperthyroidism). See the papers http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26635726 and http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27375554 for reference and methods of differential diagnosis.

Comment: I edited the sentence about L-Thyroxine.